# warnings after updating to xcode 4.4.1 for RestKit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, restkit

When I updated Xcode to 4.4.1 It gives me 22 warning for using RestKit Library. The error was like this:

```
Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
```

I fixed 18 warnings by replacing:

Replace `%lu` with `%u`

Replace `object->isa` with `object_getClass(object)`

Replace `keyObject->isa` with `object_getClass(keyObject)`

There are 4 more warnings that I cannot fix it, here are the warnings following by its descriptions:

file Name 1: RKManagedObjectMappingOperation.m
Warning Line1:

```
NSAssert(mapping, @"Attempted to connect relationship for keyPath '%@' without a relationship mapping defined.");
```

Warning Description1:

```
more '%' conversations than data arguments
```

File Name2: RKReachabilityObserver.m
Warning Line2:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p host=%@ isReachabilityDetermined=%@ isMonitoringLocalWiFi=%d reachabilityFlags=%@>",
            NSStringFromClass([self class]), self, self.host, self.isReachabilityDetermined ? @"YES" : @"NO",
            self.isMonitoringLocalWiFi ? @"YES" : @"NO", [self reachabilityFlagsDescription]];
```

Warning description2:

```
format specifies type int but the argument has type NSString
```

File Name3: JSONKit.m
Warning Line3:

```
if(JK_EXPECT_F(((id)keys[idx])->isa != encodeState->fastClassLookup.stringClass) && JK_EXPECT_F([(id)keys[idx] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == NO)) { jk_encode_error(encodeState, @"Key must be a string object."); return(1); }
```

Warning Description3:

```
Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
```

File Name4: NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.m
Warning Line 4:

```
RKLogError(@"Property '%@' not found in %@ properties for %@", propertyName, [propDict count], NSStringFromClass(self));
```

Warning description4:

```
format specifies type id but the argument has type NSUInteger
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you filed bugs on RestKit's GitHub project for these issues? Better yet, a pull request with the fixes!

Comment: No, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Their issue tracker is here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues (which would be a good place to look first if you run into more bugs later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning 1:

```
NSAssert(mapping, @"Attempted to connect relationship for keyPath '%@' without a relationship mapping defined.");
```

becomes

```
NSAssert(mapping, @"Attempted to connect relationship for keyPath '%@' without a relationship mapping defined.", <<put the corresponding keyPath here >> );
```

or

```
NSAssert(mapping, @"Attempted to connect relationship for a keyPath without a relationship mapping defined.");
```

it said "more '%' conversations than data arguments" meaning that you have placeholders, in this case %@, but no arguments to fill them. So either provide an argument or delete the placeholder.

Warning 2:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p host=%@ isReachabilityDetermined=%@ isMonitoringLocalWiFi=%d reachabilityFlags=%@>",
        NSStringFromClass([self class]), self, self.host, self.isReachabilityDetermined ? @"YES" : @"NO",
        self.isMonitoringLocalWiFi ? @"YES" : @"NO", [self reachabilityFlagsDescription]];
```

becomes

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p host=%@ isReachabilityDetermined=%@ isMonitoringLocalWiFi=%@ reachabilityFlags=%@>",
        NSStringFromClass([self class]), self, self.host, self.isReachabilityDetermined ? @"YES" : @"NO",
        self.isMonitoringLocalWiFi ? @"YES" : @"NO", [self reachabilityFlagsDescription]];
```

notice the `isMonitoringLocalWiFi=%d` part gets `%@` instead of `%d`, because you provide a string argument but have an integer placeholder.

Warning 3: Sorry can't help you with this one. Probably after I take a look at the code I'll post an update.

**update:** try changing

```
((id)keys[idx])->isa
```

to

```
object_getClass( ((id)keys[idx]) )
```

Warning 4:

```
RKLogError(@"Property '%@' not found in %@ properties for %@", propertyName, [propDict count], NSStringFromClass(self));
```

becomes

```
RKLogError(@"Property '%@' not found in %d properties for %@", propertyName, [propDict count], NSStringFromClass(self));
```

notice the second placeholder should be `%d` and not `%@` since you provide an integer or in this case a NSUInteger, i.e. `[propDict count]` argument.

Comment: Awesome, it fixed all of the warnings, Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Rose you're welcome :) Let me know if you still need help understanding those warnings.